# Reserved ILPIP / internal DNS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I created a Ubuntu-VM (classic) and want to ssh into it without using the public IP from the cloudservice. I know how to create an ILPIP and it works fine, but when I shutdown & restart my VM, the ILPIP changes - I want to avoid that. I know I can reserve a public IP, but is there a possibility to have a reserved **ILPIP**?

Another solution would be to use DNS names. In `/etc/resolv.conf` I can see some kind of internal DNS, it looks like this: `mycloudservice.f8.internal.cloudapp.net`. So I used putty and tried to ssh using this DNS name: `myvm.mycloudservice.f8.internal.cloudapp.net` but sadly I get an error: `Host does not exist`. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The internal DNS works using the private IP space of your vnet, not the ILPIP, so it's only available from within the vnet.

If sounds like you're trying to use putty from outside the vnet, is that correct?

thanks
Gareth (MSFT)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So I can't access my VM using a specific DNS name? And as I read [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/static-public-ip-addresses-available-for-azure-virtual-machines/) I also can't reserve ILPIP? So there is no solution for my problem?

Comment: the article says that ARM deployed static IPs can be reserved, is moving to ARM deployment an option (ARM is the new Azure deployment model and the recommended one for new things).